# jQuery not working for getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use Bitstamp API. But somehow it is not working.

This is the code:

```
$.getJSON("https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/", function(person){

$.each(person, function(key, value){
    document.write(key+":"+value+"<br />"); 
});

});
```

And here is jsfiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/mojit/QKTrD/

I am not getting what is wrong here. As when I run the API url on browser it works. But it is nor working when I try to access its parameter using jQuery.

I tried to replace the url with other's API url like MtGox and MtGox works perfectly. But Bitstamp's doesn't.

Can anybody tell me whats going wrong?

Will really appreciate.

Thanks.

Comment: What error do you see in the console?  If you look in the network tab and the response for that call, what do you see?

Comment: https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker&callback=? bitstamp doesn't support jsonp format, so I'm sorry but you can't get what you want.

Comment: It's a cross domain request and therefore not permitted. It doesn't look like bitstamp offers jsonp either, so I think you're pretty much out of luck.

Comment: `document.write` is a document killer when invoked after page load. It will immediately stop and kill also your Javascript code ... I am not surprised that it doesn't work that way

Comment: Would a reverse proxy be feasible?

Comment: @devnull69 hey what is the alternative to document.write then?

Comment: Every other DOM manipulating method like `element.innerHTML`, `element.appendChild()`, `element.insertBefore()` etc. would be feasible, in combination with element getter methods like `document.getElementById()` or `document.getElementsByClassName()` etc

Comment: @devnull69 Thanks. Replaced the document.write with document.getElementById() and innerHTML.

Comment: @user2206724 please check my answer and give the green tick on the left side of my answer if it solved your question thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access a data from another domain. It is called cross-domain request and it is not normally allowed. There is a technique called jsonp and you should check if this is supported by bitstamp. If not, then you should make a proxy. By proxy I mean some local file which uses some server side technology to make get requests. You may implement this in php, nodejs or whatever you are using. And then your js code will make request to a file on your server.

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: "proxy.php",
  data: { url: "https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/" },
  success: function(result) {
    $.each(person, function(key, value){
      // ...
   });
  }
});
```

So, just pass the url which you want to fetch data from.

Comment: Very useful info. Will try this as bitstamp doesn't support jsonp. Thanks.

Comment: You won't be able to succeed like this ... but go for it :-)

Comment: @devnull69 I agree about the document.write and I remove it, but why you think that it will not work. It's pretty easy to perform a curl request to that url and get the json.

Comment: Now that document.write has been removed, it will work (given that `proxy.php` is implemented correctly)

Comment: It depends on your exact code. If you do something like `document.getElementById('elementid').innerHTML = "your output goes here"` it should be fine